# почему при делении отрицательных чисел программа зависает, например: -8/-2

Tags: swift4

```
let value = "\(newValue)"
let valueArray = value.components(separatedBy: ("."))
if valueArray [1] == "0"{ Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
    displayResultLabel.text = "\(valueArray [0])"
} else {
    displayResultLabel.text = "\(newValue)"
}
stillTuping = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы же сами написали почему программа падает:

> if valueArray [1] == "0"{ Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Значит `valueArray` содержит только 1 элемент.

`newValue` Double? Если Int, то десятичной части не будет.
Также нужно проверить локаль. Десятичным разделителем может быть `,`

Если оперируете числами - не нужно использовать строки, пример как проверить наличие десятичной части:

```
if newValue.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0 {
    displayResultLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", newValue)
} else {
    displayResultLabel.text = "\(newValue)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

у меня такая же ошибка была, тк была небольшая опечатка в самом начале

let value = "(\newValue)"
исправил на

let value = " \ (newValue)"